# How to create Gmail Labels with Google Apps Script for all users in an organization

Tags: google-apps-script, label, gmail-api

I want to create a Google Apps Script to create labels for all the users in the organization.
We have Google Workspace and I have already enabled Gmail API at Advanced Google services.
I want a main Label with some sub-labels.

example (it is working):

```
function createLabel() {
const labels = ["L1","L1/S1","L1/S2","L1/S3"]
labels.forEach(l => Gmail.Users.Labels.create({name:(l)}, "me"))
}
```

1. I add the labels only to me. How do I add it to everybody?
2. I also saw that if the label exists I get an error so I also need to check each user before creating the label and maybe just skip if a label exists.

**Edited**

I managed to add an error check so it will skip if a label exists. Still need help looping on all the organization users.

```
function createLabel() {
  const labels = ["L1","L1/S1","L1/S2","L1/S3","L1/S4"]
  labels.forEach(l => 
  {
    try {
      Gmail.Users.Labels.create({
        name:(l),
        "color": {
          "backgroundColor": "#662e37",
          "textColor": "#662e37"
        }
      }, "me")}
    catch{}
  }
  )
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a service account and configuring domain wide deligation.

You can then add the lables to each of the users on the domain one at a time.

using a service account with app script is a little tricky though